# Pipe and white smoke come out to the exhaust pipe

Tags: troubleshooting, mitusbishi

1999 Mitsubishi RVR.

Small amount water and smoke come out in tail pipe when I first turn it on in the day. But sometimes no water and smoke come out. I don't know what is the problem or it is normal.

What is the white smoke that comes out of my tail pipe when I first start my car?

Comment: Does the smoke only happen for a little bit, or does it continue even after the car is warmed up? Smell the exhaust ... does it have a sweet smell to it?

Comment: I smell like water. No sweet smell on it. A little bit happen and the water last for 5minutes but the smoke last for 10minutes

Comment: Are you having to fill up the coolant? Does it become low over time?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you have condensation forming in the exhaust system.  When you start up the hot exhaust gases boil it off and you get a puff of steam.  you don't say exactly where you live, but does the smoke come and go with humidity or dewpoint?

Comment: I live in queenstown new zealand. How many minutes test to warm up the engine. And check the exhaust? Its hot here now.

Comment: Well, my theory doesn't make sense given then amount of time you say the smoke is happening.  Condensation would be a puff for a few seconds.  @paulster is asking good questions that would give better info.

Answer (score 0):

It also could be drain down from leaky valves where oil is dripping into the combustion chamber.  Are you loosing any oil?  When the white smoke comes out - if you hold a piece of glass, does it condense and then go away or does some oily residue remain?

Answer (score 0):

White smoke is usually moisture, oil would have a blueish tint to the smoke. Also, condensation can from high humidity which would accumulate in the exhaust system.

Check your oil and look for moisture, a blown/leaky head gasket could cause the white smoke. To test it, after the car has been running for a while and engine temperature has been brought up to up normal, shut off your motor and wait a few minutes before restarting. If the there still is white smoke, I would seriously check the head gasket.